# Using http.createServer with Express

Tags: node.js, express

Can someone see the problem in this code? It must be something simple but I can't see it.

```
var express  = require('express');
var debug = require('debug')('untitled1:server');
var http = require('http');

var app    = express();
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/API',router);
app.route('/book').get(function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index');
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen('3000');
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

...

Comment: What's the actual problem that you're having?

Comment: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
   at new View (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:62:11)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   at C:\Users\David\Documents\training\nodeJS\server.js:11:7
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next

Comment: You are trying to render a template called `index` and Express has no idea which template engine to use for that. See [the fine manual](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an view engine. Try to add this line, it should solve your problem.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```